# How to remove properties from an object array?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to remove a property from an object array.

```
export class class1 {
  prop1: string;
  prop2: string;
  prop3: string;
}
export class class2 {
  myprop = [
    { prop1:'A', prop2:"1", prop3:"descr1" },
    { prop1:'B', prop2:"2", prop3:"descr2" },
    { prop1:'C', prop2:"3", prop3:"descr3" },
  ];
  get(): class1[] {
    return this.myprop ;
  }
  add(value: class1): void {
    this.myprop.push(value);
  }
}
var var1 = class2.get();
var var2 =
```

I would like var2 contain something like this.

```
  [
    { prop1:'A', prop3:"descr1" },
    { prop1:'B', prop3:"descr2" },
    { prop1:'C', prop3:"descr3" },
  ];
```

Is there a way to convert/cast `var1` into the above? In other words, I would like to remove `prop2` from `var1` object array and assign it to `var2`. How can I do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can delete object property like this e.g.

```
    var myprop = [
        {prop1: 'A', prop2: "1", prop3: "descr1"},
        {prop1: 'B', prop2: "2", prop3: "descr2"},
        {prop1: 'C', prop2: "3", prop3: "descr3"},
    ];

    myprop = myprop.filter(function (props) {
        delete props.prop2;
        return true;
    });
    console.log(myprop);
```

Comment: That’s not where you would use `filter`. You’d use filter to remove or keep _items in an array_, not properties. `delete`, here, creates side-effects. This answer is using `filter` in a completely unsemantic way as a general-purpose iteration method.

Comment: Perfect, thanks! Sometimes the good old JS (or at least its newer versions) is so much more readable then lodash or other libs..

Answer (score 23):

This seems like a great time to use `.map()`

```
var var1 = class2.get();
var var2 = var1.map(obj => ({prop1: obj.prop1, prop3: obj.prop3}));
```

Short, sweet, and does what you want.

[MDN docs for .map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: Maybe even shorter :D `var1.map( ({ prop1, prop2 }) => ({ prop1, prop2 }) );`

Answer (score 1):

Casting in TypeScript won't remove the property but only hide it in your IDE because it will be compile to JavaScript for runtime.

First of all, if you don't want to remove `prop2` from `var1` while deleting the property from `var2` you need to clone it. For that you will need this JavaScript function:

```
function cloneObject(obj) {
    if (obj === null || typeof obj !== 'object') {
        return obj;
    }

    var temp = obj.constructor(); // give temp the original obj's constructor
    for (var key in obj) {
        temp[key] = cloneObject(obj[key]);
    }

    return temp;
}
```

Use the clone function to clone `var1` and loop each object in `var2` to remove property `prop2`. You can do so with JavaScript by combining array.forEach and delete:

```
var var2 = cloneObject(var1);
var2.forEach((obj) => { delete obj.prop2; });
```

Doing so will KEEP `prop2` in `var1` but REMOVE it from `var2`

Answer (score 0):

```js
// Use delete:

    var user = {
      firstname:"Jack",
      lastname:"Prince",
    };

    var result = delete user.firstname;
    console.log(result,"firstname deleted");
    console.log(user);
    
    
    
  //using Object rest spread operator 

   const { firstname, ...data } = user;
   console.log(data);
```