# How can I edit the value of an array

Tags: javascript

I have an example:

```
var A = [{
  key: "iphone",
  value: "American"
}, {
  key: "sony",
  value: "Japan"
}]
```

I want to do this action:

```
B=[{value:"American"},{value:"Japan"}]
```

How can I do this? Help me.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Have you tried anything so far? StackOverflow isn't a free code-writing service, and expects you to [**try to solve your own problem first**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592). Please update your question to show what you have already tried, showcasing a **specific** problem you are facing in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please see [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove properties from an object array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37222885/how-to-remove-properties-from-an-object-array)

Answer (score 2):

Use **[`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)** and return a new Object with the value field,

**DEMO**

```js
var A =[{key:"iphone",value:"American"},{key:"sony",value:"Japan"}] ;

var result = A.map(d => ({ value: d.value }));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Using a single liner implied return would be preferable here

Comment: var A = [{
  key: "iphone",
  value1: "American1",
  value2:""American2",
  value3:""American3",
  value4:""American4",
}, {
  key: "sony",
  value1: "japan1",
  value2:""japan2",
  value3:""japan3",
  value4:""japan4",
}]
==>
 B = [{
  value1: "American1",
  value2:""American2",
  value3:""American3",
  value4:""American4",
}, {
  value1: "japan1",
  value2:""japan2",
  value3:""japan3",
  value4:""japan4",
}]
can i  delete "key"

Answer (score 1):

`var B = A.map(function(obj) { return { value: obj.value }; });`

or

`var B = A.map(obj => ({ value: obj.value }));`

Comment: Sorry, forgot parentheses around the fat arrow when returning an object. Was that why you down-voted?

Comment: Thanks @CommercialSuicide but you edit broke the solution. Edited back.

Comment: Sorry, my correction was wrong, I restored the original solution and gave upvote

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you prefer this more readable syntax?

```
function myObjectConverter (inputObject) {
  var outputObject = {};
  // ignore the key property
  outputObject.Country1 = inputObject.value1;
  outputObject.Country2 = inputObject.value2;
  outputObject.Country3 = inputObject.value3;
  outputObject.Country4 = inputObject.value4;
  // transfer any other items with new names
  return outputObject;
}

var B = A.map(myObjectConverter);
```