# Returning an Array of Objects.... from an Array of Objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

```
people: [
  {
    name: "Jon Doe",
    age: "25",
    city: "Detroit",
  },
  {
    name: "Jane Doe",
    age: "23",
    city: "Detroit",
  },
  {
    name: "Jack Doe",
    age: "22",
    city: "Detroit",
  },
  {
    name: "Joe Doe",
    age: "28",
    city: "Detroit",
  },
  {
    name: "Josh Doe",
    age: "27",
    city: "Detroit",
  }
]
```

TO THIS ------------>

```
anotherArray: [
  {
    name: "Jon Doe",
    city: "Detroit"
  },
  {
    name: "Jane Doe",
    city: "Detroit"
  },
  {
    name: "Jack Doe",
    city: "Detroit"
  },
  {
    name: "Joe Doe",
    city: "Detroit"
  },
  {
    name: "Josh Doe",
    city: "Detroit"
  }
]
```

How would I achieve this result? I just want to pull certain keys from each object, then make an object of those selected keys. Intuitively, I am thinking maybe the .map method but so far each attempt has been a failure.

> **NOTE:** There is a similar question [How to remove properties from an object array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37222885/how-to-remove-properties-from-an-object-array). This is not a duplicate question, because I am not trying to DELETE anything from the object, and I attempting to create a new object with specific results.

Comment: `people.map(x => {delete x.age; return x;})`

Comment: Share your attempt with `map`

Comment: @izengod `delete` mutates the original objects.

Comment: this is NOT a duplicate question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend using .map :

```
//Using your above people array:

people.map( ({name, city}) => ({name, city}) )
```

This should return the array you're looking for.

Comment: ahhh this solves the problem. Learned something today. Can't believe I didn't think to use .map this way originally.

Answer (score 0):

Use `.map` on the array and inside the callback delete the key `age`.

```js
var data = {
  people: [{
      name: "Jon Doe",
      age: "25",
      city: "Detroit",
    },
    {
      name: "Jane Doe",
      age: "23",
      city: "Detroit",
    },
    {
      name: "Jack Doe",
      age: "22",
      city: "Detroit",
    },
    {
      name: "Joe Doe",
      age: "28",
      city: "Detroit",
    },
    {
      name: "Josh Doe",
      age: "27",
      city: "Detroit",
    }
  ]
};

var newData = data.people.map(el => { delete el.age; return el; });

console.log(newData);
```

Comment: .... duh. Lmao thank you very much

Comment: Note that this modifies the original objects.

Comment: @JJJ thats correct! Thanks for mentioning...

Comment: Why downvotes? Care to explain?