# How to return not all of the properties of an object from arrays with an array method?

Tags: javascript

I want to use an array method with arrow function. For an example:

```js
const inventory = [
    {name: 'apples', quantity: 2, type: 'a'},
    {name: 'bananas', quantity: 0, type: 'a'},
    {name: 'cherries', quantity: 5, type: 'a'}
    {name: 'mangos', quantity: 5, type: 'a'}
];

const result = inventory.filter( fruit => fruit.quantity === 5 );
```

What if i want to return just the object with the name and type properties? Like this:
    `console.log(result) //[{name: 'mangos', type: 'a'}, {name: 'cherries', type: 'a'}]`

Comment: If you want a new object with fewer properties, then return a new object. Seems like you first want to `.filter()` with the given predicate before mapping the new objects though.

Comment: FYI, your line `inventory.map( fruit => fruit.quantity === 5 );` will return an array of `true`/`false` values. Not sure if that's what you're after there.

Comment: `map(({ quantity, ...rest }) => rest)`

Comment: @CrazyTrain `rest` is already an object, no need to create an object from an object.

Comment: @Li357: Ah yeah, you're right. For some reason I thought it returned a temporary collection like `.entries()` returns.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove properties from an object array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37222885/how-to-remove-properties-from-an-object-array)

Answer (score 3):

You'd create a new object. It looks like you want to do *two* things, though: Filter to only items with quantity of 5, *and* return objects without the quantity field. Unelss you have hundreds of thousands of these¹, you'd do that by using `filter` then `map`. Here's an example with destructuring:

```js
const inventory = [
    {name: 'apples', quantity: 2, type: 'a'},
    {name: 'bananas', quantity: 0, type: 'a'},
    {name: 'cherries', quantity: 5, type: 'a'},
    {name: 'mangos', quantity: 5, type: 'a'}
];

const result = inventory
  .filter(fruit => fruit.quantity === 5)
  .map(({name, type}) => ({name, type}));

console.log(result);
```

---

¹ If you *do* have hundreds of thousands of these or more, you might consider just making one pass with `forEach`.

Answer (score 1):

```
inventory.filter(fruit => fruit.quantity === 5).map(fruit => ({ name: fruit.name, type: fruit.type }));
```

map creates a new array using the values you give it, but doesn't change the original, filter creates an array using only the values the function returned a truthy value for.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the `type` property by destructuring:

```js
const inventory = [
    {name: 'apples', quantity: 2, type: 'a'},
    {name: 'bananas', quantity: 0, type: 'a'},
    {name: 'cherries', quantity: 5, type: 'a'},
    {name: 'mangos', quantity: 5, type: 'a'}
];

const res = inventory.map(({type: x, ...rest}) => rest);

console.log(res);
```

Or you can just make your array.map callback returning object having only name and quantity field:

```js
const inventory = [
    {name: 'apples', quantity: 2, type: 'a'},
    {name: 'bananas', quantity: 0, type: 'a'},
    {name: 'cherries', quantity: 5, type: 'a'},
    {name: 'mangos', quantity: 5, type: 'a'}
];

const res = inventory.map(({name, quantity}) => ({name, quantity}));

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score -4):

Try using [lodash](https://lodash.com/)

```
const inventory = [
    {name: 'apples', quantity: 2, type: 'a'},
    {name: 'bananas', quantity: 0, type: 'a'},
    {name: 'cherries', quantity: 5, type: 'a'}
    {name: 'mangos', quantity: 5, type: 'a'}
];

const result = ._map( inventory, (item)=> { 
    return {
             name: item.name, 
             quantity: item.quantity}
} );
```

Comment: Why lodash's map instead of the method by standard?