# How to remove specific column from data array (JS)

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a list

```
let list = [ 
{ 
  id: "247", 
  order_number: "21251", 
  tel: 13911111, 
  weight: "10kg" 
}, 
{ 
  id: "245", 
  order_number: "223", 
  tel: 31, 
  weight: "10kg" 
},
{ 
  id: "123", 
  order_number: "312312321", 
  tel: 3213123, 
  weight: "10kg" 
}
];
```

Now I only wan to remove the specific column, such as 'tel', to get a new list. Is there any elegant way to do it? or I have to loop the whole data to use splice method?

Comment: `findIndex` followed by `splice`, surely that's straightforward enough?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove properties from an object array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37222885/how-to-remove-properties-from-an-object-array), though you should pick the highest voted answer, not the accepted one, or the comment underneath it — in your case: `list.map(({id, order_number, weight}) => ({id, order_number, weight}))`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would argue **against using delete keyword** because **you would be mutating the list instead of making a new one**, and also because of its behavior explained in the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete), Specially those lines about:

- Any property declared with let or const cannot be deleted from the scope within which they were defined
- If a property with the same name exists on the object's prototype chain, then, after deletion, the object will use the property from the prototype chain (in other words, delete only has an effect on own properties).
- Any property declared with var cannot be deleted from the global scope or from a function's scope.

Instead you can `map()`.

```
listWithoutTel = list.map(({ tel, ...item }) => item);
```

Here you'd be using the [rest parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) to put all properties **but** the unwanted one (in this case `tel`) of a [destructured object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) in a variable named `item` and return in immediately.

Comment: if the property is like 'tel num' , how to handle it? @Christopher Francisco

Comment: Best answer I've seen.  Cheers!

Comment: How could you make "tel" a variable?

Comment: @Ian I understand its pretty old post but did you get solution to your comment?

Comment: @Ian using https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment link from anwer post Its possible to pass feild name with space like listWithoutTel = list.map(({ 'tel num':telnum, ...item }) => item);

Answer (score 2):

In static way:

```js
let list = [
  {
    id: "27",
    order_number: "21251",
    tel: 13911111,
    weight: "10kg"
  },
  {
    id: "245",
    order_number: "223",
    tel: 31,
    weight: "10kg"
  },
  {
    id: "123",
    order_number: "312312321",
    tel: 3213123,
    weight: "10kg"
  }
];
let new_list = list.map(function(obj) {
  return {
    id: obj.id,
    order_number: obj.order_number,
    weight: obj.weight
  }
});

console.log(list);
console.log(new_list)
```

This way, you keep both your old array and new array.

If you want to do it in dynamic way, you may use `forEach` to check the keys.

Comment: Can this be made dynamic? User can select what columns to be removed (tel or tel and weight, ...)?

Answer (score 0):

Use `delete` operator to remove the tel key from all objects in a loop

```js
let list = [ 
{ 
  id: "247", 
  order_number: "21251", 
  tel: 13911111, 
  weight: "10kg" 
}, 
{ 
  id: "245", 
  order_number: "223", 
  tel: 31, 
  weight: "10kg" 
},
{ 
  id: "123", 
  order_number: "312312321", 
  tel: 3213123, 
  weight: "10kg" 
}
];
var list2 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(list));
for(i in list2) {
   delete list2[i].tel;
}

console.log(list2);
console.log(list);
```

Comment: The OP specified a new list. You have to first create a shallow copy of the array before deleting `tel`

Comment: Updated the answer. please check now @MaxK

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you aren't going to find a way without looping. If you think about it, in order to delete the key from every object it will need to loop over it no matter what even if it's just a loop disguised as a simple function.

As far as simplicity goes I would recommend using:

`list.forEach(function(x){delete x.tel});`

```js
let list = [ 
{ 
  id: "247", 
  order_number: "21251", 
  tel: 13911111, 
  weight: "10kg" 
}, 
{ 
  id: "245", 
  order_number: "223", 
  tel: 31, 
  weight: "10kg" 
},
{ 
  id: "123", 
  order_number: "312312321", 
  tel: 3213123, 
  weight: "10kg" 
}
];


list.forEach(function(x){ delete x.tel });

console.log(list);
```

Comment: You could do this without looping: [Remove attribute for all objects in array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18133635/4642212). You could even do this with some setup of a [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy).

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but in this case since every object has the key as opposed to a select few, wouldn't looping be just as efficient as another method because in both cases you will go to each index?

Comment: You won’t iterate over each index, if you mutate [a single prototype](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18133757/4642212). You could also proxify the array or the objects and alter a few Proxy handlers to make the objects behave as if they didn’t have the `tel` property. Both approaches are `O(1)` rather than `O(n)`.

Answer (score -2):

You can use delete keyword.

```
delete myObject.prop
```